# Lucene.NET - What is the Version parameter in MultiFieldQueryParser constructor?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

We're running into a serious bug with the Lucene.NET 2.3 codebase. We're upgrading to Lucene 2.9 in hopes the bug is fixed.

Upgrading to the latest version, we see that the MultiFieldQueryParser contructor is [Obsolete]:

```
[Obsolete("Use the ctor with Version param instead.")]
public MultiFieldQueryParser(string[] fields, Analyzer analyzer)
```

Instead, we're to use the constructor that takes a Version parameter:

```
public MultiFieldQueryParser(Version version, string[] fields, Analyzer analyzer)
```

Problem is, I can't find any documentation regarding what the version parameter is, what it's supposed to be, what I'm supposed to pass in here.

Can anyone shine some light on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The version parameter was added to provide backwards compatibility in a way that can be extended to accommodate future changes.

If you don't care about backwards compatibility, just use `Version.LUCENE_CURRENT`. If you really need to know exactly what changed, you usually have to go diving into the source code.

General Lucene tip: you usually get better documentation looking at the [java version](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html).

Comment: In 3.0.1, Version.LUCENE_CURRENT is deprecated http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/changes/Changes.html#3.0.1.api_changes
So, use the actual version number.

Comment: Are you kidding me? Jeez. Actual version number...ok...Version takes 2 params. A string and an int. Where's the documentation for this?

Comment: Ah, there it is: Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29 as documented here:  http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/util/Version.html